# Build & execute a stack of void functions

Tags: c++, function, stack

I am trying to store a vector(or stack) of functions. The idea is that I have a series of functions that add & remove widgets to the main window. I use a timer alarm & whenever the alarm is called I call the function at the top of the stack of functions.

**So my functions will always be of type void. My problem/misunderstanding is how to delcare a stl::stack of void functions & how do I execute that function?**

```
class InstructionScreen
{

  std::stack <void*> instructionSteps;  // is this how I declare a stack of functions

  void runTimerEvent()
  {
      if ( !instructionSteps.empty() ) 
      {
          // call the function at the top of the stack
          // how do I call the function?
          (*instructionSteps.top()); // is that how?
          instructionSteps.pop();
      }
  }

  void step1()
  {
     // here I create some widgets & add them to the main window
  }

  void step2()
  {
     // delete widgets from window
     // create some different widgets & add them to the main window
  }

  void buildStack()
  {
     instructionSteps.push( (&step1()) ); // is this correct?
     instructionSteps.push( (&step2()) );  
  }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

A `void*` pointer is not a legal function pointer. It should be `void (*)()`, which can be made nicer with a `typedef void (*stack_function)()`.

```
std::stack<stack_function> instructionSteps;
```

To push something into it, you don't call the function (like you do with `step1()`) and you certainly don't take the address of the return (which is void anyways) like you do with `&step1()`, you just use the function name alone:

```
instructionSteps.push(step1); // the & can be omitted for free functions
instructionSteps.push(&step2); // equivalent to the above, only a different function
```

To call stuff from the top of the stack, you actually need to *do* a call:

```
(*instructionSteps.top())();
//    you missed that -- ^^
```

The dereference can be omitted too for reasons that would take too long to explain here, search SO. :)

```
instructionSteps.top()();
```

Comment: @Maxpm: Well, to get a pointer to a member function, you need the `&`: `&MyClass::my_func`. I can see where you're coming from, though, the wording is a bit ambiguous. Changed that.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for a static function pointer is like so:

```
void (*FuncPtr)();
```

For a member pointer you have to use this syntax:

```
void (class::*FuncPtr)();
```

If your functions does not require the functions to be member functions it is a lot cleaner. Once you figured out what kind of functions you need it's easiest to typedef these functions like so:

```
typedef void(*FuncPtrType)();
typedef void(Class::*MemberFuncPtrType)();
```

Now you can simply declare a stack with function pointers like so:

```
std::stack <FuncPtrType> funcPtrStack;
std::stack <MemberFuncPtrType> memberFuncPtrStack;
```

To get a pointer to a function you simply use the "&" operator like you would to get an address to any other data type in C++:

```
FuncPtrType funcPtr = &staticFunc; // Somewhere "void staticFunc()" is defined
MemberFuncPtrType memberFuncPtr = &Class::MemberFunc; // Somewhere void "Class::MemberFunc()" is defined
```

To actually call the function pointers, you would use the "*" operator to get the data back from the pointer (just like any other data type in C++). The only tricky thing is for member functions they need a pointer to the class which makes it very awkward to use. That's why I recommended using static functions to begin with. In any case, here is the syntax:

```
(*funcPtr)(); // I just called a function with a pointer!
(this->*memberFuncPtr)(); // I just wrote some ugly code to call a member function
```

Having shown all that, the following code should now make sense:

```
std::stack <MemberFuncPtrType> memberFuncPtrStack; // Declaring the stack
memberFuncPtrStack.push( &Class::MemberFunc ); // Pushing a function
(ClassPtr->*memberFuncPtrStack.top())(); // Calling the function with ClassPtr
```

Comment: Your code for calling a member function is wrong, it has to be `(obj.*mem_fun_ptr)();`, the `.*` is one operator. Better even for pointers, just use the `->*` operator: `(obj_ptr->*mem_fun_ptr)();`

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `typedef` and make a `vector`/`stack` of it:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)();
std::stack<funcptr> instructionSteps;
```

Usage:

```
instructionSteps.push(&step1);
instructionSteps.push(&step2);
```

See [demo here](http://www.ideone.com/oCQyI).
Execution:

```
instructionSteps.top()();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Use Boost.Function, it's a lot easier. It will not only store functions with precisely the right type, but also anything else that can be called in the same way.

```
std::stack<boost::function<void()> instructionSteps;
int foo() { return 42; }
instructionSteps.push(foo); // Close enough - return value will be discarded.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void (*fptr)();
class InstructionScreen
{

  std::stack <fptr> instructionSteps;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would `typedef` the function pointer to make your life easier:

```
typedef void(*voidFunctionPointer)(); // Assuming here that the functions take no arguments.

std::stack<voidFunctionPointer> instructionSteps; // This is very different from <void*>.  
                                                  // The latter is merely a stack of void pointers.
```

One way of calling the top function is this:

```
voidFunctionPointer functionToCall = instructionSteps.top();
functionToCall();
```

If you want to do it without an extra declaration, I *think* this should work.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
instructionSteps.top()();
```

To build the stack, just use the function name without any trailing parentheses.

```
instructionSteps.push(step1);
instructionSteps.push(step2);
// ...
```